# A certain covering space of the figure eight

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

J.R.Munkres in his book (page 373) has described a certain covering space $E$ for the figure eight $X$ as follows:
 Let X be the union of two circles A and В in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose intersection consists of the single point $x_0$.
The space $E$ is the subspace of the plane consisting of the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis, along with tiny circles tangent to these axes, one circle tangent to the $x$-axis at each nonzero integer point and one circle tangent to the $y$-axis at each nonzero integer point. The projection map $p:E\longrightarrow X$ wraps the $x$-axis around the circle $A$ and wraps 
the $y$-axis around the other circle $B$; in each case the integer points are mapped by $p$ into the base point $x_0$. Each circle tangent to an integer point on the $x$-axis is mapped homeomorphically by $p$ onto $B$, while each circle tangent to an integer point on the $y$-axis is mapped homeomorphically onto $A$; in each case the point of tangency is mapped onto the point $x_0$.

I'm going to define the fucntion $p$ exactly to investigate the conditions of definition of covering space but I could not do it. Could you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you not know the formula for wrapping a line around a circle?

Comment: To add to Lee Mosher's comment, you will handle the $x$-axis and $y$-axis by the circle wrapping formulas. How exactly you handle the circles in $E$ will depend on how you choose to attach them to the $x$ and $y$ axes and what their radii are. I would not expect a "nice" single line formula for $p$; it will likely need to be piecewise-defined.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes. The exponential map  $\exp :\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ by $\exp (t)=e^{2\pi it}$.

Comment: @AdamLowrance Thank you for the comment. Your mean is that I can define for example $p_0 :\mathbb{R}\times \{ 0\} \longrightarrow X$ by $p_0 (t,0)=\exp (t)$ and also on other pieces of the domain, then I use the gluing lemma, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Good luck!

Comment: @AdamLowrance Thank you very much for your help.